# Is it possible to split project into several folders?

Tags: arduino-ide

It is possible to split the project into server files. However, it looks like they all must be in the same folder with the.ino file.

Is it possible to split project into several folders? I’ve got several git repositories which I want to use in the same project and I can’t use them as libraries. Each repository must have its own folder…

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: @Majenko Win10. Does it matter for this case? All things are quite similar everywhere nowadays.

Comment: Yes you can. It works and many projects use subfolders. And NO, you will not see them in your Arduino IDE. As st2000 said, Arduino IDE is simple and people likes it because it is simple. If you want the control of your processor and code, use PlatformIO.

Comment: @Adriano how? I can refer the headers in subfolders but Arduino IDE does not compile the definitions from subfolders. And, guys, how you even can call it `simple`? Looks like things are simple only for simple deeds.

Comment: If you have a header inside a subfolder, you can just call `#include "subfolder/header.h"` and it works. You can see this big project for example: https://github.com/xoseperez/espurna/tree/dev/code/espurna - but you will not see the files inside the Arduino IDE. Simple means, that if you don't have programming skills, you are able to open and edit something without loose time to find out what an IDE is and how it works. In future, with the PRO version, it will be easier to develop something... I hope ;)

Comment: @Adriano As I said, I have no problem with headers. I have .cpp files inside a subfolder. How to make IDE compile them? I don't need to work with them via IDE, it's ok.

Comment: @zhekaus I wrote the answer as answer, not as comment. Hope this is ok for you. I know what you want. You want the comfort of Visual Studio in a simple text editor with integrated compiler. You can use Visual Studio + Visual Micro and you will have all the comfort you want ;) But Arduino IDE also gives you a lot of options to develop more complex projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to give an answer as it is not easy to understand what you mean.

Probably it is also better if you know how the Arduino IDE works, before try to make complex projects.

Short answer:
**Yes, it is possible**

Normally, you have an ino-file, some other files and many libraries. If you want create something for your project, you can just create a folder inside the library folder.

But this is not what you want right?

You can create many folders inside your project and include any header inside your folders just with
`#include "subfolder/yourfile.h"`

The files will not be opened with your Arduino IDE.

You can also create your "mini library", so the compiler will compile it with your project. This library need to be in a subfolder called `src`. At this point it will be converted and compiled for your project.

Simple working example:
**testsub.ino**

```cpp
#include "src/test.h"
Test *test = new Test();
void setup(){
  Serial.print(test->number());
}
void loop(){
}
```

Create a subfolder `src` and place your files:
**test.h**

```cpp
class Test
{
public:
  Test();
  int number();
};
```

and
**test.cpp**

```cpp
#include "test.h"
Test::Test() {
}
int Test::number() {
  return 95;
}
```

If you want another "library", you can create another subfolder called `src`.

Comment: You know, that's finally quite something! Thank so much!
However, how can I have extra subfolder with the same name `src`?

Comment: You need to place the second subfolder inside the src folder. And there, you can place another src folder. This is the only way at the moment.